# Wide to long with multiple columns

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse

I'm trying to convert my dataset from wide format to long format, but it's not working as intended. My dataset has columns `rowid, arrest1, arrest2, ..., arrest10, lien1, lien2, ..., lien10` and looks something like this:

```
rowid   arrest1   arrest2   ...   lien1     lien2   ...
1       1/1/2008  NA              2/2/2009  NA
```

I'm trying to get a long dataset where I have a time variable that takes on the values 1-10 and separate variables `arrest` and `lien` that contain the dates. I tried the following code, but my time variable takes on values 0-9 and in addition to the `arrest` and `lien` variables, there are `arrest1` and `lien2`. There's definitely something wrong with the `names_pattern` argument.

```
df_long <- df_wide %>%
  select(rowid, lien1:lien10, arrest1:arrest10) %>%
  pivot_longer(-rowid,
               names_to = c(".value", "time"),
               names_pattern =  "(\\w+).*?(\\d{1,2})")
```

Here's some sample data:

```
structure(list(rowid = c(9317L, 31447L, 37939L, 40198L, 19346L
), arrest1 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), class = "Date"), arrest2 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), arrest3 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), arrest4 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), arrest5 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), arrest6 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), arrest7 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), arrest8 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), arrest9 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), arrest10 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), lien1 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), lien2 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), lien3 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), lien4 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), lien5 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), lien6 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), lien7 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), lien8 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), lien9 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), lien10 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `names_sep` (with regex lookaround - `names_sep = "(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)"`) or capture as groups in `names_pattern` (`names_pattern = "(\\D+)(\\d+)"` - here we are capturing one or more non-digits (`\\D+`) as a group (`(...)`) followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) separately that corresponds to the vector passed in `names_to` i.e. ".value" will the value of the columns that for 'arrest', 'lien' and the "grp" will create the new column with the suffix digits from the column names)

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df_wide, cols = -rowid, names_to = c(".value", "grp"), 
     names_pattern = "(\\D+)(\\d+)")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 50 × 4
   rowid grp   arrest lien  
   <int> <chr> <date> <date>
 1  9317 1     NA     NA    
 2  9317 2     NA     NA    
 3  9317 3     NA     NA    
 4  9317 4     NA     NA    
 5  9317 5     NA     NA    
 6  9317 6     NA     NA    
 7  9317 7     NA     NA    
 8  9317 8     NA     NA    
 9  9317 9     NA     NA    
10  9317 10    NA     NA    
# … with 40 more rows
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks so much. What does the regular expression \D+ do? Will accept your answer when I can.

Comment: @user122514 i added some explanation